# Look and say type constant

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, closed-form

I have been fascinated by integer sequences such as the look and say sequence and its many variant.

USUALLY such sequences grow like $ a n^b $ or like $ c n ^ d $ where $a,b,c$ are algebraic Numbers or algebraic number raised to an algrbraic power ( like $ \sqrt 2 ^{\sqrt3} $).

Very often we meet the golden mean or conways look and say constant ( = algebraic integer ).

For Some reason i was not able to find links to most of them.

But here are some
( i might add more later )

[1]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence

[2]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

[3]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_sequence

[3] grows like $ \phi^{2 - \phi} n^{\phi -1} $.

All these closed form asymptotics are fascinating me.

Also this one ( no link or name ?? )

Consider the sequence

$1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,...$

where $a_1=1,a_{n+1}\in\{a_n,a_n+1\}$, and $a_n$ is the number of times $n$ occurs in the sequence.  Then if we assume that $a_n$ grows asymptotically as $\alpha n^\beta$, we get

$\alpha=\phi^{1/{\phi^2}}$

$\beta=1/\phi$.

For all $n$ the asymptotic expression is well within one unit of the actual $a_n$.

Etc etc

But recently I was thinking more of a fibonacci kind of look n say.

Let $f(1) = 1$.

$f(2) = f(2 - f(1)) = 1$.

$f(3) = f(3 - f(2)) + f(3 - f(1)) $

Etc

I found it here !!

http://oeis.org/A052109/list

So what is the limit of $ f(n) / f(n-1) $ when $n$ goes to positive $\infty$ ?

Does the limit have a closed form ?

Comment: Why do you write "look n say" rather than "look and say"?

Comment: The short answer is ' a,d ' David K :). Basically and is more formal. It is like I am and I'm or something.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say in that last comment, other than that you don't like to write in mathematical English. If you want to make yourself understood to most of the people who might see your question, I suggest a change in writing style. Ultimately, of course, it's up to you to decide whether it's worth that effort to court answers.

Comment: I edited a bit now.

Comment: FWIW, it seems very clear that the ratios converge to a value approximately equal to $2.4384384738$, and plugging this into the Inverse Symbolic Calculator turns up no useful information.

Comment: I got a similar result Steven. But thanks for the digits. Btw i placed a bounty on another question if you are looking for another challenge :)