# The sequence A126022 : $a_{n+1} = a_n + \lfloor a^{-1}(n+1) \rfloor $

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, closed-form

Consider the sequence A126022 at OEIS

http://oeis.org/A126022

$$ 1,2,4,7,10,13,17,21,25,30, ... $$

We start with $a_1 = a(1) = 1$.

$a_n = a(n)$ and $^{-1}$ means functional inverse.

By $\lfloor a^{-1}(n+1) \rfloor$ we mean $\max K $ such that $a_K = a(K) $ and $a_K = n+1 $ or $a_K < n+1$.

( check the link If you are confused , Leroy explains it more clearly )

If this self-reference reminds you of the look and say sequence , that is normal.

In fact this question was inspired by a similar question I asked

[Look and say type constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907298/look-and-say-type-constant)

And Also my mentor.

So here again I ask for understanding and more specific asymptotics with closed form values.

It might be intresting to note the very similar - in fact a motivation also for this question - equation pointed out by my mentor :

$ F'(x) = F^{-1}(x) $

That can be solved by plugging in

$$ F(x) = r x^t $$

And solving for $r,t$.

So I assume a good asymptotic to $a(n)$ is $ j x^k $

And of course the idea that $t = k$ and/or $r = j$ comes naturally.

So far the main ideas.

I have not done numerical tests yet.

It seems intuitive and easy , but I have No results at the moment.

---

A second question is the analogue sequence associated with $ G ' (x) = G^{-1}(x-1) $.

---

Comment: By $\operatorname{floor}(\operatorname{inv} a_n)$ do you mean $\max\{k \mid a_k \leq n \}$?

Comment: Are you sure about $a_9=26$?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Oh !! I need to edit !!

Comment: I suggest I close for a while to fix it

Comment: I edited. It is a bit better now. Good enough to be understood. Voting to reopen !

Comment: The leading asymptotic behavior seems to be $\varphi\left(\frac{n}{\varphi}\right)^\varphi + \alpha n $ for some $\alpha \approx -\frac18$. In fact, using available data from OEIS, we have $\left|a_n - \left( \varphi\left(\frac{n}{\varphi}\right)^\varphi - \frac{n}{8}\right)\right| < 1$ for $n$ up to $57$.

Comment: I assume golden mean there. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $\varphi$ is the golden mean. BTW, I take back the part about $\alpha n$ correction. Generate $a_n$ myself for $n$ upto $10000$, the difference $a_n - \varphi\left(\frac{n}{\phi}\right)^\phi$ doesn't look linear at all.

Comment: So my mentor's intuition was correct.

Comment: By does not look linear do you mean flat ( like constant or zero ) or not ? Like a sqrt ? Power ? Log ??

Comment: does look like anything at all. see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgLpr.png) for the difference $a_n - \varphi\left(\frac{n}{\phi}\right)^\phi$ for $n$ upto $20000$.

Comment: Thanks achille, that looks intresting !

Comment: It seems the error is with the order of $\sqrt n \ln \ln ((n)) $